# Context Menu Item for ListBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, contextmenu

I want to display ContextMenu on right click of ListBoxItems in WPF. I tried below code, but ContextMenu is displaying where ListBoxItems are not there also. What I want is to display ContextMenu only on the right click of only ListBoxItems.

```
<Grid>
<ListBox x:Name="listofConnectedItems" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" MouseRightButtonDown="listofConnectedItems_MouseRightButtonDown" ContextMenuOpening="listofConnectedItems_ContextMenuOpening" >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10">

                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="_Start" Click="MenuItemStart_Click"  />
                <MenuItem Header="Sto_p" Click="MenuItemStop_Click" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Clear" Click="MenuItemClear_Click" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBox.ContextMenu>

    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

`
Here I attached the screenshot.[image]
Can anybody Please get me through this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try setting it in `ItemsContainerStyle` for `ListBoxItem` instead of whole `ListBox`

Comment: You are setting CM now for entire LB.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan CM property is not found in ListBoxItem. That is what I am asking, how to place CM only to ListBoxItems.

Answer (score 1):

It should be in `IntemContainerStyle`:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
       <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ContextMenu>
                   <MenuItem Header="Open" />
                   <MenuItem Header="Edit" Command="Binding 
               </ContextMenu>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that You didn't specified height and width of list box so it automaticaly scales to the window size. So technically Your code is working correctly but listbox is everywhere.

try with something like

```
<ListBox x:Name="listofConnectedItems" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="5" Width="200" Height="200"...
```

and then rightclick outside the listbox

Comment: I said ContextMenu is displaying in listbox where listboxitems are not present. Height is not the problem. In runtime I am adding listboxitems, so I didn't specified the height.